# merging two objects together

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object which have the data like this

```
 let TokenToStore = { "googleRefreshToken": refreshToken, "googleAccessToken": accessToken, "google_expires_in": expiryTime}
```

now I want to merge this object with object in my session (**req.session.contextToken**)

What I initially tried was

Consider my `req.session.contextToken` already having data for meetup token.

```
console.log(req.session.contextToken)
//{googleRefreshToken: '1/k_C4Iub8OzxZQMG_3sXRD5-9kZ8kqMDzhr-RW_0XB4G13kY7M8-FE6gX5r3ko',
//googleAccessToken: 'ya29.GluJuh7q6Ly3br-pzum_d9ue0zxEERN6VA0FJvvaXJyJvXDWGIJm7yDTECe7WzEq33dR8EgyOIJ-Bn5dn23RS4fqrA2IctzXjbZ_n5dVxPo3Z',
//google_expires_in: 1547418864123}
```

Now to merge I did something  like this (TokenToStore is in the first code snippet mentioned above)

```
 req.session.contextToken = {...req.session.contextToken, TokenToStore}
```

Hoping it will give following response

```
    {meetupRefreshToken: 'vb8OZQMG_3sXRD5-9kZ8kqMDzhr-RW_0XB4G13kY7M8-FE6gX5r3ko',
      meetupAccessToken: 'ya9.Guh7q6Ly3br-pzum_d9ue0zxEERN6VA0FJvvaXXDWGIJm7yDTECe7WzEq33dR8EgyOIJ-Bn5dn23RS4fqrA2IctzXjbZ_n5dVxPo3Z',
      meetup_expires_in: 1547418864123,
      googleRefreshToken: '1k_C4IuaZQMG_3sXRD5-9kZ8kqMDzhr-RW_0XB4G13kY7M8-FE6gX5r3ko',
      googleAccessToken: 'ya29.GluQBq6Ly3br-pzum_d9ue0zxEERN6VA0FJvvadVxPo3Z',
      google_expires_in: 1547418864123}
```

but instead it gave following response

```
    {meetupRefreshToken: 'vb8OZQMG_3sXRD5-9kZ8kqMDzhr-RW_0XB4G13kY7M8-FE6gX5r3ko',
          meetupAccessToken: 'ya9.Guh7q6Ly3br-pzum_d9ue0zxEERN6VA0FJvvaXXDWGIJm7yDTECe7WzEq33dR8EgyOIJ-Bn5dn23RS4fqrA2IctzXjbZ_n5dVxPo3Z',
          meetup_expires_in: 1547418864123,
          TokenToStore: {
               googleRefreshToken: '1k_C4IuaZQMG_3sXRD5-9kZ8kqMDzhr-RW_0XB4G13kY7M8-FE6gX5r3ko',
                googleAccessToken: 'ya29.GluQBq6Ly3br-pzum_d9ue0zxEERN6VA0FJvvadVxPo3Z',
                google_expires_in: 1547418864123
                         }
     }
```

**Question:** Can someone please tell me how I can merge and achieve desired result? The one I was expecting

Comment: Use `...TokenToStore` instead of `TokenToStore`. You already did this correctly with `...req.session.contextToken`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to spread (using `...`) `TokenToStore` because you did it with `req.session.contextToken`. Use this:

```
req.session.contextToken = {...req.session.contextToken, ...TokenToStore}
```

And it will work.